# jQuery / wordpress issue with .addClass based on url

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I'm have some issues adding a class to 2 navigation links on a theme.

I need to add a class based on a url string as i'm redirecting the page to another.

I'm using the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if (window.location.pathname.indexOf('/category/blog/')){
   if ( $('#nav ul li a span').text().contains('BLOG') ){
       //add class 'current_page_item' to:
       $('#nav ul li').addClass('current_page_item');
   }
}
if (window.location.pathname.indexOf('/category/keepers/')){
   if ( $('#nav ul li a span').text().contains('KEEPERS') ){
       //add class 'current_page_item' to:
       $('#nav ul li').addClass('current_page_item');
   }
}
</script>
```

Can anyone see why that doesnt work?

I get the following error:

```
$ is not a function
[Break on this error] if ( $('#nav ul li a span').text().contains('BLOG') ){
```

Comment: did you include jquery correctly in that file?

Comment: Yes, uses built in wordpress jQuery... Now get the following error:
$("#nav ul li a span").text().contains is not a function [Break on this error] if ( $('#nav ul li a span').text().contains('BLOG') )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$("#nav ul li a span").text() returns a string, not a jQuery object.
You cannot call contains on a string, that is the problem.
Info on the text() function [here](http://api.jquery.com/text/).

I think you need to restructure the way you are doing your logic,
$("#nav ul li a span").text() returns the following string:
HomeBlogBioAboutKeepers
So your contains logic will evaluate to true on every page of your site.

I think a better way to do it would be to loop through the li elements, get the text within an individual li span and then set that individual li's css when it is true.

HTH

EDIT:
This works (I tried it on your site in firebug):

```
jQuery('#nav ul li').each(function(){
    //The comparison is case sensitive, Dont use uppercase like in your original
    if(jQuery(this).find('span').text() == "Blog"){ 
        jQuery(this).addClass('current_page_item');
    }
});
```

Comment: That helps a lot, i've changed the code to: 

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
if (window.location.pathname.indexOf('/category/blog/')){
$('#nav ul li').each(function(){
    if($(this).find('span').text() == "Blog"){ 
        $(this).addClass('current_page_item');
    }
});
}
});
</script>

Comment: However, if i'm on the home page, its display the active state for the blog AND home....

I only want the blog li class to have 'current_page_item' when the url contains 'category/blog/'??

Comment: Ahhh i missed if (window.location.pathname.indexOf('/category/blog/') > -1)

Answer (score 0):

you should put that lines into

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     // here
});
```

Comment: Added that and still same error,

i also tried: 
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

but that throws this error:

$("#nav ul li a span").text().contains is not a function
[Break on this error] if ( $('#nav ul li a span').text().contains('BLOG') ){